# Can I open Unity project created with 2017.2.1p3 with similar version?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

To what extent are differences in Unity versions acceptable?
Do they need to be exactly the same version?
I want to open a project created with ver2017.2.1p3.
Can I open with 2017.1.5f1 or 2017.2.5f1 or higher?

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: it will upgrade it which ever version you use that is newer.  All versions have pros and cons, some fix a and break b kinda deal, going to 2018 or 2019 will add bigger changes and somethings maybe less compatible, but all should be fixable

Comment: Usually going upwards is no trouble .. especially while staying under the same major release (2017.2). Going downwards often works as well but it always depends on the features a project uses. Also going upwards some breaking changes might exist so read the release notes. It's basically the same as switching between OS versions etc .. there might or might not always be some hickups but ofcourse Unity tries to keep them as small as possible ;) **Always make backups though**

Comment: Sometimes Upgrading a project will create issues if you're using various third party libraries/plugins like Google SignIn, ads, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine to do it, in the past I've found that sometimes going jumping a full version (e.g 17-18) will cause the metadata to be cleared which detaches all objects from where they've been assigned through the inspector so just remember to take a backup.

My advice would be to step through the versions,  try the highest 2017 version, then 2018, then the latest version, as long as you have a backup you can't really go wrong.